# How do I change shutter speed in manual mode in an Olympus OM-D E-M5?

Tags: shutter-speed, olympus, manual-mode

How do I change shutter speed in manual mode in an Olympus OM-D E-M5?

Comment: Have you read the manual? What have you tried so far? What worked, what didn't work? Have you googled for the answer? What did you find?

Answer (score 1):

> In mode M, you choose both the aperture and the shutter speed. [...] After rotating the mode dial to M, **rotate** the main dial to choose the aperture and **the sub dial to choose the shutter speed**.

It's all there in the [Olympus E-M5 User Manual](http://cs.olympus-imaging.jp/en/support/imsg/digicamera/download/manual/omd/man_em5_e.pdf), page 58.